# add 2 objects to JFrame on a specific location

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

This is my class that creates a circle shape with specific x and y coordinates. Similarly I have another same class but with different x and y coordinate positions. I create 1 object of each class and want to display them on specific positions on JFrame.When I add 2nd object to JFrmae, it overwrites the 1st object. I tried with different layouts of JFrmae but it did not work.

```
  class Ballbewegung2 extends JPanel implements Runnable {  
    int x_pos = 10; int y_pos = 100; int radius = 20; 
    public void init() { 
    setBackground (Color.blue); } 
    public void start () { 
    Thread th = new Thread (this); 
    th.start (); } 
    public void run () { 
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 
    while (true) { 
       x_pos ++; if(x_pos >= 400) x_pos = 10; 
       repaint();
       try { Thread.sleep (20); } 
       catch (InterruptedException ex) {}       thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_
PRIORITY); } } public void paint (Graphics g) { g.setColor (Color.red); g.fillOval (x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius); } }
```

Comment: So you're repainting from a separate thread? Is this how the other circle class looks? I have to say I'm a little confused.

Comment: The other class is exactly the same one but with different position of y-coordinate.i.e. in other class, I am just changing the vlaue of y_pos, rest is the same.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

If you make the layout of the JFrame null, you will be able to explicitly control the position of any component that you add. Also make sure that you are adding to the content pane of the JFrame.

Comment: this this solve your problem? could you please select this as the answer if so. If not, please explain why it didn't help.

Comment: to clarify - I doubt that the panels are actually being overwritten, it's just that the layout puts them on top of each other. Make the layout null, then specifing x and y should work fine.